# How do I get value from textarea which contains div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textarea which contains some HTML (don't ask me why! :))

The HTML looks something like:

```
<div class="text-tag">some gibberish 1</div> 
<div class="text-tag">some gibberish 2</div> 
<div class="text-tag">some gibberish 3</div>
```

How do I get values from it namely: some gibberish 1, some gibberish 2 and some gibberish 3?

**Edit:**

My HTML look like this:

```
<textarea>
    <div class="text-tag">some gibberish 1</div> <div class="text-tag">some gibberish 2</div>  <div class="text-tag">some gibberish 3</div>
</textarea>
```

This html is typed by the user and I need to parse the HTML this is typed by user in textarea.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by HTML in your textarea? Is the example markup above lacking opening an closing `<textarea>` tags or is the HTML something that someone typed in the textarea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var alltext = [];

$('div.text-tag').each(function() {
  alltext.push($(this).text());
});

console.log(alltext.join(', ')); // output: some gibberish 1, some gibberish 2, some gibberish 3
```

or

```
​var alltext = $('div.text-tag').text();
console.log(alltext); // output: some gibberish 1some gibberish 2some gibberish 3
```

or

```
var alltext = [];
$('div.text-tag').text(function(index, text) {
   alltext.push(text);
});
console.log(alltext.join(', '))​​; // output: some gibberish 1, some gibberish 2, some gibberish 3
```

#### According to your edit:

```
var content = $($.trim($('textarea').val())),
    alltext = [];
$(content).each(function() {
  if(this.nodeType != 3)
      alltext.push($(this).text());
});
console.log(alltext.join(', '));
```

[**Sample workout 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/uQ5Ud/)

​
Another sample:

```
var textarea = $("textarea").val(),
    alltext = [];
$(textarea).filter(function(index, item) {
   if($(item).hasClass('text-tag'))
       alltext.push($(item).text());
})
console.log(alltext.join(', '));
```

**[Sample workout 2](http://jsfiddle.net/XWp4b/1/)**

​

Comment: But, question is how do I find it with respect to the html I got from textarea?

Comment: how does you `textarea` contains `div`? post your `textarea`'s HTML in your question or make a fiddle

Comment: Thanks. Here is how I did it:  var val = $(textarea).val();    $(val).find('div.text-tag').prevObject.each(function () {...});

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is better but I'd use the following code for your task:

```
var values = [];
$(​$(​"textarea").val()​​​​​​).filter(".text-tag").each(function() {
    values.push(this.innerHTML);
});​​​​​​​
console.log(values);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/XWp4b/